# How can I find what network manager my installation is using?

Tags: networking, 18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 (server) on a VirtualBox VM, and I'm trying to install Pihole on it in a container.  One of the things you need to do is stop using the built-in DNS service **systemd-resolved.service**.  I'm following [this guide](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/run-pihole-in-docker-on-ubuntu-with-reverse-proxy/#Step_1_Modify_Ubuntu_Network_Configuration) which mentions you can use `network-manager` to restart the service if you wish.  However, network-manager doesn't appear to be on my VM.

Why is this missing, and what can I do to find out what is running in its place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network Manager is missing because it is a graphical application. This is typically not available in a server installation. Networking in Ubuntu 18.04 server edition is handled by *netplan*. You can check its configuration with:

```
cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
```

You can find more information here: https://netplan.io/ and, especially, here: https://netplan.io/examples