# How can I restart the network on 18.04 with netplan?

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying to do some stuff with docker in 18.04 Bionic Beaver (sever version!) which requires disabling the DNS resolver

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved.service
```

Since all of the usual network tools don't appear to be available, I was [pointed in the direction of netplan](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110435/273458), specifically `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` which returned

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

So, being the lemming that I am I created `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg` and populated it with `network: {config: disabled}`  I wanted to restart the network, and the suggestion I kept finding was

```
sudo netplan apply
```

which returned:

> sudo: unable to resolve host generic: Resource temporarily unavailable

where my hostname is **generic**.  I assume this is because I stopped resolution?  But I think I'm back to my original problem because I'm following [this guide](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/run-pihole-in-docker-on-ubuntu-with-reverse-proxy/) which says you need to add `dns=default` to NetworkManager.config.  I assume I must add something similar for BB, but I wouldn't know where to put it.

Comment: Do you also have dnsmasq running?

Comment: It's not installed

Answer (score 0):

Add `renderer: networkd` to the config file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
```